# NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: [id="faturaspnl.aba"]

Tags: python, selenium

I have some troubles with this code. I'm learning about selenium and I try to get a element by id from html, but the console says: NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: [id="faturaspnl.aba"]. How can I fix this error?

My code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

from time import sleep

from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

navegador = webdriver.Firefox()

link = "https://teste.com"

navegador.get(link)

user = "****"

password = "*****"

sleep(1)

campo_user = navegador.find_element_by_id('login-input-usuario-id').send_keys(user)

campo_password = navegador.find_element_by_name('senha').send_keys(password)

button_enter = navegador.find_element_by_id('login-button-id').click()

sleep(5)

button_consultas = navegador.find_element_by_id("menu-consultas").click()

sleep(1)

button_relatorio = navegador.find_element_by_id("faturaspnl.aba").click()
```

I imported the html code if need

[image: Html]

My Error code from console, help me :c

```
NoSuchElementException                    Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-85417135cfdf> in <module>
     33 sleep(1)
     34 
---> 35 button_relatorio = navegador.find_element_by_id("faturaspnl.aba").click()
     36 
     37 #button_perfil = navegador.find_element_by_id('appbar-menu').click()

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py in find_element_by_id(self, id_)
    358             element = driver.find_element_by_id('foo')
    359         """
--> 360         return self.find_element(by=By.ID, value=id_)
    361 
    362     def find_elements_by_id(self, id_):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py in find_element(self, by, value)
    974                 by = By.CSS_SELECTOR
    975                 value = '[name="%s"]' % value
--> 976         return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
    977             'using': by,
    978             'value': value})['value']

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py in execute(self, driver_command, params)
    319         response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
    320         if response:
--> 321             self.error_handler.check_response(response)
    322             response['value'] = self._unwrap_value(
    323                 response.get('value', None))

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py in check_response(self, response)
    240                 alert_text = value['alert'].get('text')
    241             raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)
--> 242         raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
    243 
    244     def _value_or_default(self, obj, key, default):

NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: [id="faturaspnl.aba"]
```

Comment: Save `navegador.page_source`(https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.page_source) to a text file just before the line that causes the error then inspect said file using a text editor. Search for the id and if found, check if it's within an IFRAME.

Comment: Are you sure that `id` value is not different when you open the website in webdriver? Or maybe that DOM is into `iframe`?

Comment: @JustinEzequiel I did it, but i dont know what i do. I saw that the html have many tables but i dont know reference the id of div.

Comment: `NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: [id="faturaspnl.aba"]` says just that. Selenium cannot find that ID. Again, save the `navegador.page_source` attribute to a text file since that is what Selenium sees and **not the HTML from your browser**. Again, if a search through the text file finds the ID, check if the element is within an IFRAME.

Comment: @JustinEzequiel look my answer bellow

Comment: Still does not rule out an IFRAME around the element with `id="faturaspnl.aba"` since you've posted just the DIV start and end tags.

Comment: @JustinEzequiel but into the div does not exist an iframe.

Comment: If you feel that Selenium is wrong about the structure of your HTML then perhaps you should file a bug report. Only **you** can see the HTML from `.page_source` so there's nothing else I can suggest.

Comment: @justiEzequiel mannn, thank youuu, you were right, sorry. I found the IFRAME that encompassed the div. I managed to solve it, thanks.